# Font error when clicking Attribute Relationships tab in Dimension Designer in SSDT

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssas, cube, sql-server-data-tools, dimensional-modeling

I am new to SSDT and I'm following the Analysis Services Tutorial called [Multidimensional Modeling (Adventure Works Tutorial)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db55e226-601a-4026-8651-573195555a59(v=sql.110)).  And I'm currently on Lesson 3, on the step [Modifying the Customer Dimensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5b5aed99-1760-4bc7-b248-52ecb0b97ebc(v=sql.110)) under the heading "Modifying Attribute Relationships".

When I open the Dimension Designer window for my **Customer** Dimension, if I click on the **attribute** tab, I receive a long error message.  I've been searching online and found nothing about this error.  does anyone know what is the cause of this error?  I've checked my font folder and I have Arial font already.

```
 ===================================

 An error prevented the view from loading. (Microsoft Visual Studio)

 ===================================

 Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. (mscorlib)

 ------------------------------
Program Location:

   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.SerializationInvoke(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext& context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.CompleteISerializableObject(Object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.FixupSpecialObject(ObjectHolder holder)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Resources.ResourceReader.DeserializeObject(Int32 typeIndex)
   at System.Resources.ResourceReader._LoadObjectV2(Int32 pos, ResourceTypeCode& typeCode)
   at System.Resources.ResourceReader.LoadObjectV2(Int32 pos, ResourceTypeCode& typeCode)
   at System.Resources.ResourceReader.ResourceEnumerator.get_Entry()
   at System.Resources.ResourceReader.ResourceEnumerator.get_Current()
   at System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager.FillResources(CultureInfo culture, ResourceSet& resourceSet)
   at System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager.ApplyResources(Object value, String objectName, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Graphing.GraphCtrl.InitializeComponent()
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Graphing.GraphCtrl..ctor()
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Design.AR.ARDiagram..ctor()
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Design.AR.AREditor..ctor()
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Design.DimensionDesigner.CreateAREditor(VsStyleToolBar pageViewToolBar)
   at Microsoft.DataWarehouse.Design.EditorWindow.EnsureViewIsLoaded(EditorView view)

===================================

Font 'Arial' does not support style 'Regular'. (System.Drawing)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at System.Drawing.Font.CreateNativeFont()
   at System.Drawing.Font.Initialize(FontFamily family, Single emSize, FontStyle style, GraphicsUnit unit, Byte gdiCharSet, Boolean gdiVerticalFont)
   at System.Drawing.Font.Initialize(String familyName, Single emSize, FontStyle style, GraphicsUnit unit, Byte gdiCharSet, Boolean gdiVerticalFont)
   at System.Drawing.Font..ctor(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
```

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Describe your environment from Visual Studio Help / about window - version & build for VS itself also, SQL Server Analysis Services (from the Installed Products list).  You aren't using VS 2015?

Comment: is this the information you were wanting?

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01586 SP1Rel

Comment: Go back to Help / About, then scroll down in the Installed Products list and find the entry for SQL Server Analysis Services.  What version is that?

Comment: Can you upgrade to VS 2015 with the latest SSDT?  You are using v old software.

Comment: I suppose I could, but the tutorial I'm following is tailored to VS2012.  I'm doing this for a grad school course.  If the error is related to a bug in the version, then why would it work for the microsoft people writing the tutorial?